Problem involving permutation/combination of a Poker Problem
IN the game of hearts, each of four players recieves 13 cards. What is the probablity that each player receives 13 cards of the same suit?
What I did is 4!/ (52 C 13) * ( 39 C 13) * ( 26 C 13) * ( 13 C 13) And I got around 4.47387774*10^-28 for my answer. However, the textbook suggests that the answer should be about 1.575 * 10^-12. I'm wondering whether I did something wrong or the textbook answer is wrong. Since each player have 13 cards of the same suit, we give four players 13 cards for the denominator. For the top, since they recieve the same suit, it should be 4!. I think I got all suits. Does anyone know whether I'm wrong or the textbook is wrong?

I did $\frac{\left( 4! \right) \left( 13!^4 \right)}{52!}$ and got the same answer as you. However I am not confident enough to confirm you are correct.

Yeah I'm not confident, I don't know if you should consider the suits on the numerator

FWIW, $1.575\times10^{-12}$ is likely the probability that a given player receives all the cards of a given suit. (E.g., what is the probability that you specifically get all thirteen spades?)

@TheoZhang I found this question that asks the same thing. You are right.

Looks like @pmxi and I found the duplicate at about the same time...

The question indicated that it should be 4!/ (52 C 13) * ( 39 C 13) * ( 26 C 13) * ( 13 C 13). But my question is whether it already included the ways suits are included. Like if we should consider if 1st person get 13 card with the same suit, 2nd person get 13 card or they all get 13 card at the same time

We will start by noting there are $52!$ ways to order the cards. If we let player one take the first 13, player two take the second thirteen and so on. Then we must divide by $(13!)^4$ as each set of 13 cards can be permuted without it affecting the deal. Now we should count the number of "good" deals, that is the deals in which every person gets all the colors of one suit. There are $4!$ ways to arrange the suits between the four people so you are correct in the probability of this being $\frac{4!(13!)^4}{52!}$.
As @Brian Tung pointed out in the comments, the text book answer is likely to a slightly modified question: What is the probability that you are playing hearts and get all diamonds. This would just be $(\frac{13}{52})(\frac{12}{51})\cdots (\frac{1}{40})$ because after each card we are dealt, there is one less diamond and one less total card. This yields the answer that the book gave. Note here that diamonds can be switched out for any other suit as long as it is specified. If you just want to find the probability of getting all 13 cards of the same suit then you should multiply this by 4 because there are 4 different suits.

OOH, This make so much sense now, I think the textbook meant get all diamonds but wrote the question wrong
